# Is it good practice to use appropriate data types?

Tags: c#, performance, types

This might be a stupid question but here goes:

I'm unsure whether it's habit, laziness, or the correct thing to do. But I find myself using data types that I simply don't need to use, for the sake of consistency, and making things a little bit easier to code later on (i.e casting data types).

Let me show you an example:

```
public int Number1 { get; set; }
```

Number1 is just a regular whole number, but imagine the scenario where it will **always** (or **has to be**) be a positive number, so I could in fact use uint instead of an int.

However, one of the problems with using lots of different data types is the risk of having to use explicit casting, so I would have lots of noisy code. Using common data types such as int helps to reduce the noise but would this have any effect on the overall performance of an application compared to casting?

```
int one = 2;
uint two = 1;

one = (int)two;
```

This noise isn't necessarily bad, but it can be frustrating. There could also be an issue where the uint could be higher than the maximum value of an int.

I find that in many examples, int seems to be a very commonly used data type for working with whole numbers, I very rarely see other data types being used. Why is this?

Is there anything wrong with using 'incorrect' data types, is it more efficient to use an int, rather than a uint, or a short ect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question specifically about number types, or about types in general?

Comment: My question is specifically about C# built-in types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice is to not simply use signed or unsigned numbers based on the nature of the entities that you want to represent, but to actually ***declare an entirely new data type*** for each different type of entity that you are dealing with.

So, for example, a temperature requires a signed number, but the best practice is to declare a new "Temperature" value type. (`struct Temperature`)

The beauty of C# is that:

1. If your `struct Temperature` contains nothing but a `float`, it will occupy exactly as much memory as a float would, and it will be as efficient as a `float`. (The entire `struct` will be passed around in a register just as a `float` would.)
2. You can overload operators, including type cast operators, *including implicit type cast operators*, so if your temperature needs to be freely interchangeable with some other kind of entity, you can overload the appropriate operators and achieve this without any type casts.  (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx)

It should be noted, however, that free interchangeability between data types defeats the purpose of declaring them as separate data types in the first place. What you should do instead is encapsulate as many operations as possible within the type itself, so as to minimize the situations where the type needs to be converted to something else.

***Amendment***

The practice of defining a special data type for every different type of quantity you are dealing with is derived from, and in accordance with, the practice of Physicists to always follow every single term of an equation with the units of that term.  So, length is never just a plain `5` value, it is always a `5 metres` value (in SI), and also acceleration is never just a plain `9.8` value, it is always a `9.8 metres per second squared` value. This tends to make it very evident when a mistake is being made, and therefore minimizes the chances of it happening.  For example, attempting to use a value in centimeters in an equation which expects meters, and also (even more importantly) attempting to use a velocity value in an equation which expects an acceleration value.  For more information about this, see, for example, this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138841

Making mistakes evident was also the original intention of Hungarian notation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) though at the time it was not really possible with the C language to define a different data type for each kind of value and maintain performance.  So, they just fiddled with the names of the variables.

With modern languages like C# we can finally declare our own efficient types, so that data type substitution mistakes are not just easier to catch, but actually impossible to make.

Comment: I disagree. If you start doing this, you create a whole mess of non-inter-operable types, and you add a bunch of noise with little actual benefit.

Comment: This is an interesting idea @Mike, could you provide any useful learning resources that would help to solidify my understanding of what you are proposing?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart of course, everyone is entitled to have their own opinion.  I amended my answer explaining a bit more of my reasoning.

Comment: @MikeEason not off the top of my head, (nothing that I would not have to google first,) but I amended my answer explaining a bit more of my reasoning, and in there you will find a couple of links to related subjects.

Comment: @MikeNakis Thanks, that makes things a lot clearer. Is there a special term for this process? I understand what you're saying, but I can't put this into a short sentence where google could provide any useful links. I'm happy to mark this question as answered now.

Comment: I did a quick search but was unable to find anything more specific than [Type Theory (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) and [Type System (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) which are interesting reads, although they do not seem to define any special term regarding this issue.

Comment: If I find anything, I will post.  If you find anything, please post.

Answer (score 2):

Before looking at the performance, see if the correctness of your program is compromised by this assignment:

```
one = (int)two;
```

it has a potential of overflowing `int`, which is much worse than a simple loss of a few CPU cycles.

If you know that there will be no overflow, because you have sanitized the values of `unsigned` variables (in this case, `two` is less than or equal to `int.MaxValue`) then you might as well use `int`. The reasons to go for an unsigned data type would be to gain the extra bit, or to make all operations treat the number as `unsigned`, not to gain performance or to make an implicit validation.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Framework, even for positive or zero values, Microsoft choosed to use int or long in place of uint or ulong. Why : because it's easier to avoid type casts between signed and unsigned types and potential exception on sign change on substractions that unsigned integers may imply.

So, what does using only posivite or zero values on an int mean: Using only 31 of the 32 bits. Not a problem : we have a lot of memory.

This may become a problem if you want to store binary data, in that case you will generaly use byte that is unsigned. Data size can also become important for very large data storage and in communications on slow medias. Some optimized algorithms will be written to minimize memory usage and will also use unsigned values.

What is the good practice : If you use values between 0 and 2 000 000 000, use an int, if you want to be easy to use, use ints or longs. If memory usage impact, media bandwith usage is crucial, data are of binary nature (images bits, sounds, ...) or algorithm efficiency requires use of uint or ulong, use them but be carefull during substractions : substracting a number higher than the first operand will throw an ArithmeticOverflowException.